# is it possible to buy multiple in-app products in single buying?

Tags: ios, cordova, in-app-purchase, phonegap-build

My IOS app have a feature that allows the users to add the items to cart and they can buy it in single payment. How i can do with in-app purchase.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `StoreKit` [API documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/storekit), it seems like it is not possible.

However, you could set up products in iTunes Connect, where you bundle various IAP products, and offer them to be purchased by one transaction. This way you need to predefine the bundles, but the user is still able to purchace multiple product with one signle payment.